# Ektron Error log

Tags: ektron

In Ektron ,how errors or exceptions are handled.Is there any method to handle this?
Any table in Ektron DB stores errors or exception.How we handle events using the class Ektron.Cms.EkException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the helper functions from the Ektron.Cms.Instrumentation class.
You need to enable some settings in config files to make use of these functions.

Web.config:Update LogLevel as "4"

> ```
> <!-- Determines the level of messages that are logged
>     1 = Error:  Only Errors are logged.
>     2 = Warning:  Only warnings and Errors are logged.
>     3 = Information:  Only Informationals, Warnings, and Errors are logged.
>     4 = Verbose:  Everything is logged.
>     
>     NOTE: you can configure where each message level is logged using the instrumentation.config.
>   -->
>         <add name="LogLevel" value="4"/>
> ```

Instrumentation.config:

Add "Trace" to "Verbose"

> ```
> <add switchValue="All" name="Verbose">
>   <listeners>
>     <add name="Event Log" />
>     <add name="Trace" />
>   </listeners>
> </add>
> ```

Once these changes are made in config files,you can use the helper functions.

For example,

> Exception ex=new Exception("Test Exception");
>
> Ektron.Cms.Instrumentation.Log.WriteError(ex);

(Explore the Ektron.Cms.Instrumentation class for more details)

Answer (score 6):

Errors are logged to the Event viewer by default. Under "Application"